# I'm having difficulty figuring out how to overwrite parts of the "toString" methods in superclasses (polymorphism)

Tags: java

I have a superclass "Vessel" and a subclass "Bottle". The subclass "Bottle" further has two subclasses "GlasBottle" and "PlasticBottle".

I want the following output:

> This vessel has a volume of 1
>
> This bottle has a volume of 1  and contains juice
>
> This green glas bottle has a volume of 2 and contains juice
>
> This white glas bottle has a volume of 1 and contains beer
>
> This OTHER bottle has a volume of 2 and contains cola
>
> This PET bottle has a volume of 1 and contains milk

However, I'm having problems overriding the different toString methods in each class.

This is what I get as my output:

> This vessel has a volume of 1
>
> This bottle This vessel has a volume of 1 and contains juice
>
> This green glas bottle This bottle This vessel has a volume of 2 and contains 
>   juice
>
> This white glas bottle This bottle This vessel has a volume of 1 and contains beer
>
> This OTHER bottle This bottle This vessel has a volume of 2 and contains cola
>
> This PET bottle This bottle This vessel has a volume of 1 and contains milk

As you can see from the second output, it inserts "This vessel" since that string is part of the "toString" method that I'm calling, so it makes sense that it's there. However, I want java to omit that part of the superclass when I call the `super.toString()` and only include the other necessary parts. Here are my superclass and subclasses:

```
public class Vessel {

    private int volume=0;

    public Vessel(int volume) {
        this.volume = volume;
    }

    public String toString() {
    return "This vessel has a volume of "+volume;
    }

}

public class Bottle extends Vessel {

    private String content="";

    public Bottle(int volume, String content) {
        super(volume);
        this.setContent(content);
    }

    public String getContent(String content) {
        return this.content = content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "This bottle "+super.toString()+" and contains "+content;
    }

}

public class GlasBottle extends Bottle {

    private String color="";

    public GlasBottle(int volume, String content, String color) {
        super(volume, content);
        this.setColor(color);
    }

    public String getColor(String color) {
        return this.color = color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "This "+color+" glas bottle "+super.toString();
    }

}

public class PlasticBottle extends Bottle {

    private String material="";

    public PlasticBottle(int volume, String content, String material) {
        super(volume, content);
        if(material != "PET") {
            this.material = "OTHER";
        }else {
            this.setMaterial(material);
        }
    }

    public String getMaterial(String material) {
        return this.material = material;
    }

    public void setMaterial(String material) {
        this.material = material;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "This "+material+" bottle "+super.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: What you want to do is have fields that contain the name of the object, like String thisName = "bottle". Then in your toString you just need to do return "This" + thisName + "whatever";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is *'overriding'* not overwriting.

First of all add a `getVolume()` method to your top level `Vessel` class, since your `volume` is `private`.

You can simply put the parts that change as separate methods.
So in `Bottle` you put a method like this:

```
protected String getBottleType() {
  return "bottle";
}
```

and change your `toString()` like this:

```
public String toString() {
    return "This " + getBottleType() + " has a volume of " + getVolume() + " and contains " + content;
}
```

Then in each subclass of `Bottle` you just override `getBottleType()`. For example in `GlassBottle` you just do:

```
@Override
protected String getBottleType() {
 return color + " glass bottle";
}
```

You can then actually leave out the `toString()` of the sub classes unless you wish to change the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you would avoid duplication by using the volume information of the `toString()` parent class :

public String toString() {
    return "This vessel has a volume of "+volume;
   }

But it will not give the expected result in this way :

```
public String toString() {
    return "This bottle "+super.toString()+" and contains "+content;
}
```

It will just mix  the current class and the parent class information in the built String.

What you want in the subclass is :

```
public String toString() {
    return "This bottle has a volume of " + getVolume() + " and contains "+content;
}
```

In this case you should introduce a getter to access to `volume` from the subclasses.

Note that to avoid duplication and keep the `volume` field `private` you could also write something like in the subclass :

```
public String toString() {
    return "This bottle" + toStringVolume() " and contains " + content;
}
```

And define in the parent class :

```
public final String toStringVolume(){
   return "has a volume of " + volume;     
}
```

But is it really valuable ?
It creates some indirection in the reading for not a great value.

Comment: @WoeIs add a public getter for `volume`

Answer (score 1):

> I want java to omit that part of the superclass when I call the `super.toString()` and only include the other necessary parts.

You understand that `super.toString()` returns the whole string as you defined. *"the other necessary parts"* is the thing only you are aware of. You could parse `super.toString()` to extract the parts you need, but it's tedious and folly.

A reasonable way is to access parent's properties by public getters and construct a unique `String` for each subclass ignoring how the parent represented itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest thing to do is as follows:
Remove the toString methods from GlasBottle and PlasticBottle, introduce the notion of a 'vesselQualifier' (e.g. color, material), and rewrite the toString methods in Vessel and Bottle as shown below, which obtain the paired down classname from the corresponding sub-class at runtime. I've removed all of the other unrelated code for the sake of brevity.

```
public class Vessel {
    protected String vesselQualifier() {
        return null;
    }
    public String toString() {
        String[] classNameParts = this.getClass().getCanonicalName().split("\\.");
        return "This "
                +(vesselQualifier()==null?"":(vesselQualifier()+" "))
                +classNameParts[classNameParts.length-1]+" has a volume of " + volume;
    }
}

public static class Bottle extends Vessel {
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + " and contains " + content;
    }
}

public static class GlasBottle extends Bottle {
    @Override
    protected String vesselQualifier() {
        return color;
    }
}

public static class PlasticBottle extends Bottle {
    @Override
    protected String vesselQualifier() {
        return material;
    }
}
```